# Firing events from a svelte component and hearing it from containing page

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have this code in my component that is essentially the same as
the [example in the svelte docs](https://svelte.technology/guide#firing-events):

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    assessmentMouseover(e) {
      const event = new CustomEvent('assessment-mouseover', {
        detail: 'something',
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        composed: true, // makes the event jump shadow DOM boundary
      })
      this.dispatchEvent(event)
    },
  },
  // -- snip --
}
```

I then have this code in the script tag of the HTML page that instantiates this
component which is also essentially the same as the svelte docs:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#radar');

el.addEventListener('assessment-mouseover', event => {
  console.log('got here')
});
```

However, when I trigger the event, I get this error: `this.dispatchEvent is not a function`.

I've tried a number of variations on `this.dispatchEvent()` like simply
`dispatchEvent()`, which doesn't error but also doesn't trigger the listener;
and `window.dispatchEvent()` which also fails to trigger.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those docs are from the Custom Elements section — are you compiling your components as custom elements? If not, you should use `this.fire`. (This interface will be unified in v3.)

Comment: I think so. I started with the component template and that's how we are using it. We compile the component in svelte. Then it is consumed from a React app.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction? It sounds like something is amiss!

Comment: Brice's solution below worked so I don't need to reproduce. I guess my only question now is if I have a duty to submit a pull request correcting the documentation to match Brice's solution. The key to making it work was to attach the event to `document`.

Comment: I don't think it's a solution per se — it only works if someone attaches the listener to the document. The idea of `CustomEvent` is that you can dispatch it from a specific element, and interested parties can listen for the event on that element (or its parents, if it bubbles). If there's a bug, it's in Svelte itself rather than the documentation, but we can't know if there is or not without a repro

Comment: I agree with Rich comment so I did a Repl that is specific to the element. this.dispatchEvent(event) do not dispatch but targeting the specific HTML tag where the event is attached works: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.15.3&gist=7b0b820ce452cf6d5d10ebf456627651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working case repl: https://svelte.technology/repl?version=2.15.3&gist=7b0b820ce452cf6d5d10ebf456627651

Test.html:

```
<button id="{id}" on:mouseover="doMouseOver(event)">
    {isOver}
</button>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isOver: 'Over Me!'
            }
        },

        methods: {
            doMouseOver(e) {
                const event = new CustomEvent('assessment-mouseover', {
                    detail: Math.random(),
                    bubbles: true,
                    cancelable: true,
                    composed: true, // makes the event jump shadow DOM boundary
                })

                //this.dispatchEvent(event)

                let source = e.target || e.srcElement
                source.dispatchEvent(event)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

App.html:

```
<h1>From Test: {text}</h1>

<Test id="radar"/>


<script>
    export default {
        components: {
            Test: './Test.html'
        },

        data() {
            return {
                text: 'Wait for over'
            }
        },

        oncreate() {
            const el = document.querySelector('#radar')
            el.addEventListener('assessment-mouseover', event => {
                this.set({text: event.detail})
            })
        },
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks!!! The key difference is that the event is on `document` not the element.

Comment: OK, so I updated my code to match the latest edits of this answer (no longer attaching the event to document). It's better to attach to the element, but it still doesn't match the docs. Three possibilities: 1) There is a bug in svelte, 2) the docs are wrong, or 3) the docs are incomplete because they would work under different contexts. I just don't know enough to know which is it. Do any of you?